# How to stop Edit Text cursor moving to next row using Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext

i have implemented a recycler view with edit text for input quantity, after entering the quantity in edit text and calling a method my cursor is moving to next recyler edit text, pulling keyboard again.

```
                      <EditText
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="14dp"
                        android:textColor="#333f50"
                        android:id="@+id/edt_Quantity"
                        android:text="1"
                        android:cursorVisible="false"
                        android:maxLength="2"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:padding="5dp" />
```

we have tried disabling cursor by default in xml and enabling it with following code

```
    holder.edtQuantity.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {

                holder.edtQuantity.setCursorVisible(true);


        }
    });
```

i am expecting the cursor to get invisible(preventing from moving to next recycler) once i call a method associated with it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: check this link I hope it will help you, https://stackoverflow.com/a/56573924/10758304 @Puja singh

Answer (score 0):

when you press done button in keyboard is clearFocus of edittext.

```
holder.edtQuantity.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {

             holder.edtQuantity.clearFocus();

        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: not working for me.though i removed   android:cursorVisible="false" and