# There are two keyboards appear when press on an Edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying on a view as below:

- A EditText
- A RecycleView

**Result**: When I press on edit text, then there 2 keyboards which appear in order.

- PS: THIS ISSUE DON'T HAPPEN WITH SINGLE EDIT TEXT!
- Tested on device: Samsung A5, anroid 6.0.
- Share screen shot and apk:  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Kw4DPk4iHtfXzVgrpTe4vzDwbRKvsy4X

  ```
  <EditText
  android:id="@+id/editText"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
  android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
  android:ems="10"
  android:inputType="number"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
  android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />
  ```

Comment: Also add your recyclerview's item code/xml and a screenshot of your problem

Comment: It's simple from Hello world project in Android Studio and I add 2 that views. You can see screens shot  as link that i shared above. Thanks.

Comment: Wil you please post your .xml file here? for details.

Comment: See my editted  answer.

Comment: @user3345647 Have you implemented my edit answer.

Comment: @user3345647 can you chage constrant layou to relative layout at once.

Answer (score 1):

what did you mean? on Single edit text two keyboard appear or two different keyboard appears on two edit text.

Note: I checked your app it show only number keyboard cause in edit text,`<android:inputType="number"/>`

> Here Code which you need

```
 editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

just add to your Activity.java

Comment: Hi, I press on edit text at the first, number keyboard is showed then I enter a value and done, result is other keyboard appears and I must press back key on device to come back my activity. This only occurs with view in which has a recycle view else all is ok with a number keyboard.

Comment: If you press enter then it will show second keyboard means there is another edit text defiantly, is there another edit-text? can you paste full layout activity @user3345647

Comment: Hi, I add activity_main layout to shared link. It's the same one that I posted above.

Comment: hello,I Just find out solution of your question check code add to your Activity.java ,I just tried and check @user3345647

Comment: Hi, how to come back activity when you return true in case KEYCODE_ENTER?

Comment: hello, can you briefly explain what you want to say. In above code we just ignore the result which matches KEYCODE_ENTER. Still you can perform various operations on edit text like you can use editText.addTextChangedListener(.....)  @user3345647

Comment: Hi @Mohsin Kazi, When I give edit text a value, then pressing on DONE, result there is nothing happen. Number keyboard still exist and only come back activity via using back key on device.

Answer (score 0):

At first time ,when activity lunch add this line in AndroidManifest  file  to hide keyboard.

```
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
```

And add this line in  EditText Property.

```
 android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

This will hide your keyboard and only show when you click on EditText of Particuler Type as input type is Number in your xml.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work for me. I attached manifest file to shared link above.

Comment: @user3345647 See my changes .Hope this help you.

Comment: Hi, the second keyboard will not appear now but your fix change behavior of edit text that after you press Done on number keyboard, the cursor on edit text still exist. You can improve this?

Comment: @user3345647 So you can done by validating after action done,`if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {editText.setFocusable(false);}` Or use `setCursorVisible(false);`

Comment: @user3345647 on click of button . editText.setText(" ");  . It will reset the edittext

Comment: @user3345647 Yes, you can clear text via editText.setText(" ");

Comment: @user3345647 is there any doubt yet?

Comment: Hi, edit text is entered by user. At the first, you give it a value and you press DONE, then edit text lose focusable and you can't enter another value to it.

Comment: @user3345647 .It is very simple thing .you are making simple thing very big. If User enter any number then click ok then keyboard will be hide automatically. If want to use more than one edit text below one by one then  you should not use  android:imeOptions="actionDone"

Comment: @user3345647 will you please tell me what is your exact requirement?